# Как сделать выборку за 90 дней, если дата хранится в timestamp?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Как сделать выборку за 90 дней, если дата хранится в timestamp?

```
SELECT
  `modx_site_content`.id,
  pagetitle,article,
  image,
  content,
  alias,
  vendor,
  size,
  price
FROM
  `modx_site_content`
  left join `modx_ms2_products`
  on `modx_ms2_products`.id = `modx_site_content`.id
where
  `modx_site_content`.parent = 56 and
  `modx_site_content`.`template` = 31 and
  `context_key`='web' AND
  `modx_ms2_products`.price between 0 and 3000 and
  `modx_site_content`.createdon < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 91 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете конвертировать строковое представление даты в timestamp при помощи функции `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.
Вот условие для вашей выборки:

```
AND `modx_site_content`.createdon > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 91 DAY))
```